# Cannot assign void to an implicit type variable

Tags: c#, .net

I'm not sure what's happening to my code. I'm following the course and the idea is to create in the form a place to upload image using my C# .Net + Angular gallery manager application. The error happens at `var galeria = await _galeriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync(galeriaId, true);`:

> Cannot assign void to an implicit type variable CS0815.

The following map is from my controller:

```
 [HttpPost("upload-image/{galeriaId}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadImage(int galeriaId)
    {
        try {
            var galeria = await _galeriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync(galeriaId, true);
            if(galeria == null) return NoContent();

            var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                // DeleteImage(galeria.ImagemURL);
                //galeria.ImagemURL = SaveImage(file);
            }
            var GaleriaRetorno = await _galeriaService.UpdateGaleria(galeriaId, galeria);

            return Ok(GaleriaRetorno);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, $"Erro ao tentar adicionar galeria. Erro {ex.Message}");
        }
         
    }
```

Return type of GetGaleriaByIdAsync

```
Task<Galeria> IGaleriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync(int galeriaId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

IGaleriaService

```cs
namespace GestorGaleria.Application.Contratos
{
    public interface IGaleriaService
    {
        Task<GaleriaDto> AddGaleria(GaleriaDto model);

        Task<GaleriaDto> UpdateGaleria(int id, GaleriaDto model);

        Task<bool> DeleteGaleria(int id);

        Task<GaleriaDto[]> GetAllGaleriasAsync();
    
        Task UpdateGaleria(int galeriaId, Galeria galeria);
        
        Task<Galeria> GetGaleriaByIdAsync(int galeriaId);

    }
}
```

Comment: What's the return type of `GetGaleriaByIdAsync`?

Comment: The error message seems to say that `_galeriaService.UpdateGaleria` returns just a `Task`. When you await that, you are left with no value ("void") to assign to `GaleriaRetorno`, so the compiler cannot figure out the type for that. As Mathieu asked, what exactly *is* the return type?

Comment: GetGaleriaByIdAsync return type is either void or Task. In both case, if you await it you won't get anything (void).
> The void return type of a method (or a local function) is used to specify that the method doesn't return a value. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/void)
You should just call `return Ok();`

Comment: Can you please post `IGaleriaService` itself?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  Task<Galeria> IGaleriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync(int galeriaId)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }             Sorry I'm a beginner so I'm kind of lost but instead of throw new NotImplementedException(); . I should implement something, that's right?

Comment: @Joh yes you should, but it will not resolve your problem (cause `NotImplementedException`) happens at runtime and you have compile time error.

Comment: @GuruStron I just edited the post with IGaleriaService please take a look

Comment: And last question - what is `_galeriaService`? How is it declared? Cause ATM I see nothing in the code which can lead to such compilation error.

Comment: Also note that `_galeriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync` has two parameters, so `IGaleriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync` has nothing to do with it (it has only one), it is completely other method. So again, what is `_galeriaService.GetGaleriaByIdAsync(galeriaId, true)`? Where is it declared and how does the declaration look?

Comment: I think it's this line: `var GaleriaRetorno = await _galeriaService.UpdateGaleria(galeriaId, galeria);` that is the problem, because it returns `Task`.

Comment: Please re-read [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to provide code that reproduces the error. As @GuruStron said there is no method that matches `GetGaleriaByIdAsync(galeriaId, true)` call is shown in the post.